# mysql query with subqueries returning more than one row

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got two columns of dates, `t_date` and `s_date`. I'm counting the number of records occurring where `s_date` is either the same date as `t_date` or within an n day window after `t_date` occurs.

Here is the query. It returns multiple rows.

```
select count(id)
from customers
where s_date >= t_date
and s_date <= t_date + 1
group by t_date;
```

Is there any way to design a query that contains several `sub queries` that each return multiple rows? So that I can increment the time window? Something like:

```
select (
    select count(id)
    from customers
    where s_date >= t_date
    and s_date <= t_date + 1
    group by t_date
    ) as c1,
    (
    select count(id)
    from customers
    where s_date >= t_date
    and s_date <= t_date + 2
    group by t_date
    ) as c2;
```

This query, however, returns a "`Sub query returns more than 1 row`" error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN s_date >= t_date AND s_date <= t_date + 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c1, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN s_date >= t_date AND s_date <= t_date + 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c2
  ...
FROM customers
GROUP BY t_date;
```

Comment: Way better than the sub queries the OP asked for.